# Padarn Web Server Project Throwing Exception

Tags: asp.net, windows-ce, padarn

I'm testing our OpenNetCF's Padarn Web Server.

In one of their Hands-On-Labs (HOL P101), an exception is being thrown at

```
private WebServer m_padarnServer = new WebServer();
```

The exception reads, "Exception in ConfigSectionHandler".

If you have experience with Padarn, have you received this exception before? If so, can you shed some light as to what I may do to debug this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a problem in your config file.  To know more, I'd need to see the contents your config file.  Also, where are you running, on a Windows CE device or a full-framework OS (i.e. XP, Vista, 7)?

Sending the software vendor (OpenNETCF, i.e. me) a bit more info would probably help a lot.

**EDIT**

There was a bug in the HOL code (and it was a really old binary).  I've updated the lab with a newer binary and replaced it on the site.  Re-download it to get these revisions.

Comment: I'm running WinCE 6.0 (NETCF 3.5) (on a CUWIN5500 device). I've contacted Comfile to find out what SYSGEN vars are set on the device and they are as follows:  
SYSGEN_ETHERNET 
SYSGEN_FATFS 
SYSGEN_MSXML_DOM 
SYSGEN_SHELL 
SYSGEN_STDIO 
SYSGEN_TCPIP 
SYSGEN_WININET 
SYSGEN_WINSOCK
SYSGEN_AUTH 
SYSGEN_AUTH_SCHANNEL 
SYSGEN_CERTS

Comment: FYI- I submitted an OpenNetCF Community thread (http://bit.ly/e5XkWq) that includes a screenshot (http://bit.ly/efnVN7) of where the exception is occurring as well as a c/p of the details of the exception.

Comment: Regarding the .config file, it's the .config file of the HOL P101 solution. I haven't made any changes to the solution (other than the target device).